# How to add a script into Bolt?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bolt

[image]

I have a C# script imported from asset store. I want to import it in Bolt for easier to use. I've researched for a long time, asked many people. Some of them said that I need to click into Tools - Bolt - Unit Option Wizard and add the type of the script, some of them said I just have to add it as an unit. I did all that ways but still can't achieve what I want.

Comment: Did you read the tag descriptions before using them? The `[bolt]` tag's description is _"The Bolt Protocol is a lightweight (binary) messaging protocol for databases. Bolt is statement oriented with a client-server design; originally created by the team behind Neo4j."_, whereas Bolt in the context of Unity seems to be a visual scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run the script from a flow machine(bolt visual scripting component on a object) a simple way is to assign the script to an empty object and set this object active from the flow machine. To have a reference to this object inside bolt, you need to add this object to the scene variables as a game object, then just drag and drop it inside the graph of your flow machine. Bolt flow machines and C# scripts can interact in many different ways, you can read and write variables from the graph/app/object inside the script too. If you want to know more about this, drop me a line. I hope I have answered your question. If so , remember to vote it up. If you set the object inactive, the script will stop running. I really wanna know too if there is another way, something like a node called "run script x"...